# Baby Rudin's exercise 2.21

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Here's the exercise:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be separated subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^k$, suppose $a \in A$, $b \in B$, and define:
>   $$p(t) = (1-t)a + tb$$
>   for $t \in \mathbb{R}^1$. Put $A_0 = p^{-1} (A)$, $B_0 = p^{-1} (B)$ [Thus $t \in A_0 \iff p(t) \in A$]

My problem is that I don't get just *what* is $p(t)$. Is it a mapping? If so, then what is $p(A)$? Is it a set?

I'm sorry if it sounds stupid or too elementary but I simply don't understand what is this $p(t)$ Rudin just defined. It resembles a property of convexity - but it accepts any real $t$, not just a real $t$ such that $0<t<1$.

I *think* this has something to do with convexity in finite dimensions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, $t\mapsto p(t)$ is a mapping. There is *no* $p(A)$, only $p^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: $p$ is a function that maps $t \in \mathbb R$ into $p(t) \in \mathbb R^k$. $p^{-1}(A)$ is the inverse image of $A$ under $p$. As @Dietrich points out below, $p(A)$ is meaningless, because $A \subset \mathbb R^k$ but $p$ is defined only on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you're right, I wasn't reading the question properly. Will edit my comment.

Comment: I researched for this question and couldn't find it, my bad. Thanks for the link, Dietrich.

Comment: Have a look at file:    https://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009

Comment: @Bruce Second chapter, right? Although...the solutions certainly do not bother to explain what $p(t)$ is.

Comment: One thing that still isn't clear to me. What does the presence of $a$ and $b$ in the definition of $p(t)$ mean? For each $t$, p maps *all* points from A and B into a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n}: t  \mapsto p(t)$ is a map.

Geometrically, the graph of the function is the line between the points a and b.

Btw, I dislike Rudin's approach to show that convex sets are connected. It's easier and more general to show that pathconnected sets are connected and then it's trivial to see that convex sets are connected (using the map that Rudin provides).